# How do I check if variables are next to each other in a string?

Tags: javascript, string, variables

How do I check if variables are next to each other in a string?
I have 5 variables that are listed one after another, but the user may not need to enter some in the middle. The last variable in the list impacts the one directly before it, so how would I check to see if this is true?

Thanks

Comment: You could concatenate the variables and then test if that's in the string.

Comment: e.g. `if (string.includes(var1+var2))`

Comment: so would I have to do that for
string.includes(var1+var5)
string.includes(var1+var2+var5)
string.includes(var1+var2+var3+var5)
string.includes(var1+var2+var3+var4+var5)

to test all combinations or? sorry I dont understand how this logics works im very new to this

Comment: I didn't really understand what you wanted to do with this, so I just answered the basic question. It seems like you really want to do some kind of pattern matching.

Comment: You could use a regexp like `(var1)?(var2)?(var3)?(var4)?(var5)?` then see which capture groups are empty in the result.